# Build Docker compose Issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While composing the code in docker i am getting this error, Below is the error description.

I had tried with changing some RUN commands in docekrfile.But error is not fixed.

### Below is my Complete DockerFile Code:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# Install useful tools
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils nano wget dialog

# Install important libraries
RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils build-essential git curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev zip openssl

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.0
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Install redis
RUN pecl install redis-4.0.1
RUN docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Other PHP7 Extensions

RUN apt-get -y install libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-0 mysql-client
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

RUN docker-php-ext-install curl
RUN docker-php-ext-install tokenizer
RUN docker-php-ext-install json

RUN apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN apt-get -y install libicu-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext

RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ 
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers
```

---

> E: Package 'libcurl3' has no installation candidate ERROR:  The
>   command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils
>   build-essential git curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev zip openssl' returned a
>   non-zero code: 100

Comment: Try running `apt-get update` first

Comment: Yes i already checked with this command but issue is not cleared.

Comment: Please show your full Dockerfile then please, or enough that we can try and replicate.

Comment: If possible please share your Mail ID.

Comment: Mail ID? Just add it your question.

Comment: Yes i had added my Dockerfile code

Comment: That image uses Debian Buster, which libcurl3 isn't available on (out of the box). You could use libcurl4 instead? OR you can change it from `FROM php:7.2-apache` to `FROM php:7.2-apache-stretch`.

Comment: By changing this FROM php:7.2-apache to FROM php:7.2-apache-stretch....i got the output by using this line ...thank you Jonnix